# Android GooleMap, resize polygon on drag any Polygon Point

Tags: android, android-mapview

Would you help me on How to resize ( Reduce or Extend ) the already drawn polygon on android  googlemap? onMarker Drag ?

```
 @Override
public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    p2.remove();
    p2.getPoints().add(marker.getPosition());
    googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().addAll(p2.getPoints()));
}

@Override
public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

}

private List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

}
```

Comment: Describe in your question what's wrong with above code?

Comment: I don't know how to write code for  Reducing or Extending polygon on those three events (onMarkerDragStart, onMarkerDrag and onMarkerDragEnd ). there is nothing wrong on above code